# Typescript: calling setTimeout using react-timeout fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am attempting to use [react-timeout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timeout) in my application, which I am writing in TypeScript. I am following [the "Light Switch" example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timeout#es6-classes---the-light-switch) in the documentation, in which the `setTimeout` function seems to be defined as a prop upon importing `ReactTimeout`. I gather this from this line of the example in the documentation:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    this.props.setTimeout(this.toggle, 5000) // call the `toggle` function after 5000ms 
}
```

However, when I implement it similarly, TypeScript is complaining that the property does not exist. Here (essentially) is my code. The error is noted in the comments:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import ReactTimeout from 'react-timeout';

export interface ExampleProps {
    // none at this point
}

export interface ExampleState {
    isSearching: boolean;
    searchString: string;
}

export default class Example extends React.Component<ExampleProps, ExampleState> {
        constructor (props: ExampleProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isSearching: false,
            searchString: undefined
        }

        this.onSearchChange = this.onSearchChange.bind(this);
    }

    onSearchChange(e){
        this.setState({searchString: e.target.value});

        console.log('searchString: "%s"', this.state.searchString);

        // I want to wait 3 seconds before submitting the search, to allow for typing
        // ...but I get an error here: 
        //        [ts] Property 'setTimeout' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<ExampleProps>'
        this.props.setTimeout(this.doSearch(this.state.searchString), 3000);

        //ReactTimeout.setTimeout(this.doSearch(this.state.searchString), 3000); 
        // calling it directly like this doesn't work either: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTimeout' of undefined"

     }

     doSearch(searchTerm) {
        this.setState({isSearching: true});
        console.log('Now I will go search for "%s"...', searchTerm);
     }

    render() {
        const {
            isSearching
        } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Search</h2>

                <input type="text" name="searchString" onChange={this.onSearchChange} />

                {
                    isSearching ? <span>Searching...</span> : <span>&nbsp;</span>
                }

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The error message is clear to me: `setTimeout` simply isn't in the props; but I don't know how to define it. If I create my class with `React.Component<any, ExampleState>`, TypeScript no longer complains, but I get a runtime error, *"Uncaught TypeError: this.props.setTimeout is not a function"*, which isn't surprising, really, given the previous message.

How do I explicitly set a reference to `setTimeout` from this library? Do I need to do this in my `ExampleProps`? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

react-timeout is a so called HOC component, see: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

So in order for the react-timeout component to pass it's props to your component you have to wrap your component in the react-timeout component, this is usually done through wrapping it in the export, you can see this in the examples on https://github.com/plougsgaard/react-timeout.

Basically try to remove the `default export` in front of your `class example` and on the last line of your file do `default export ReactTimeout(example)`

Comment: I attempted this. It builds properly (though I did have to specify "any" instead of "ExampleProps" in my class definition), but the last line throws an error when loaded: "Uncaught TypeError: react_timeout_1.default is not a function".